# Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1024M -Xmx2024M docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have allocated pod max of 2 gb size in kubernetes but facing out of memory exception so I was trying to set heap size in my docker container but i am facing following error **Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1024M -Xmx2024M** not sure whats wrong  while running a container, due to which pod is not able to come up

**Docker file**

```
  #Stage1
    FROM openjdk:11 as JarBuilder
    ARG UNIQUE_ID=$UNIQUE_ID
    ARG COMPONENT_VERSION=$RELEASE_VERSION
    ARG REPO_USER_NAME=$SAP_ARTIFACTORY_USR
    ARG REPO_PASSWD=$SAP_ARTIFACTORY_PSW
    LABEL maintainer="ank"
    LABEL timeevent.uniqueId=$UNIQUE_ID
    WORKDIR /workspace
    COPY . /workspace/
    RUN ./gradlew timeevent-processing-service:build --scan -PcomponentVersion=$COMPONENT_VERSION jacocoRootReport -DsapRepoUsername=$REPO_USER_NAME -DsapRepoPassword=$REPO_PASSWD
    #Stage2
    FROM busybox:1.32.0 as toolsbox
    FROM openjdk:11 as final
    LABEL maintainer="ank"
    USER nonroot
    COPY --from=toolsbox /bin /usr/local/bin
    COPY --chown=nonroot --from=JarBuilder /workspace/timeevent-processing-service/build/libs/*.jar /tep/timeevent-proccessing-service.jar
    
    WORKDIR /tep/
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xms1024M -Xmx2024M", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-cp", "/tep/timeevent-proccessing-service.jar", "org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher"]
```

due to below line in docker creating problem

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xms1024M -Xmx2024M", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-cp", "/tep/timeevent-proccessing-service.jar", "org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher"]
```

Comment: You need to provide `"-Xms1024M -Xmx2024M"` as two parameters. The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @tgdavies two param in the sense are you trying to say this  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xms1024M", "-Xmx2024M", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-cp", "/tep/timeevent-proccessing-service.jar", "org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher"]

Comment: Yes, the error message is telling you that `-Xms1024M -Xmx2024M` is an invalid initial heap size, because each parameter you pass to ENTRYPOINT is interpreted as a single parameter by exec, there is no parsing happening.

Comment: @tgdavies thx for your input let me try and see

Comment: @tgdavies thx it works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
To solve this you just have to split Xmx and Xms in two parameters:

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xms1G", "-Xmx2G",....]